# Is there a better way of setting a blank display annotation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In an MVC4 project I'm using Data Annotations on the model but with a 4 lines of addresses fields (ie address1, address2, etc), I only want to label the first line with *Address* the the subsequent lines to be blank or not labelled .  If you leave out the *Display* annotation, then the field name is returned as the label so I then tried:

```
[Display(Name="")]
```

but I got the yellow screen of death for that:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
```

according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name.aspx)  I should be able to set and empty string or null in the Name value, but that's clearly not happening, so I eventually just put a space in the Name value, eg:

```
[Display(Name=" ")]
```

and that works - but it's not elegant. It seems to me that there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

as per the msdn [DIsplayAttribute.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name.aspx)

> Do not use this property to get the value of the Name property. Use
>   the GetName method instead. A null value or empty string is valid.

```
[Display(Name=string.Empty)] //may be this will work.
```

Comment: Unfortunately String.Empty produces a compile time error: 'An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type'.